# Geotools quickstart package org.geotools does not exist

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I am a newbie at Geotools and Maven as well. I tried the quickstart to start using the geotools and it all works well until the moment I try to create the example application. All imports starting with `org.geotools` are flagged as non-existent. Looking for dependencies shows no matches. This happens in Netbeans as wel as in Eclipse, obviously I am doing something wrong.

In Netbeans I did a clean and build which yielded the following results:

```
Failed to execute goal on project tutorial: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.geotools:tutorial:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:13.2, org.geotools:gt-swing:jar:13.2: Could not find artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:13.2 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Could someone help at this?

Using java 1.8.0.73, Netbeans 8.1, Eclipse 4.5.1 and Geotools version 13.2. I got the same errors using version 14.2.

**Update**
Thye pom.xml file is shown below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>13.2</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: for future reference please say which version of the documentation you are using, this was correct on both [stable](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/) and [maintance](http://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/) - and will be fixed on latest with the next build (https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1114).

Answer (score 0):

A am not able to do a comment so that is why I answering here.
Can you show us pom.xml?
Also, did you run `mvn clean install?`
After this command all libraries in pom should be downloaded, and should exisit.

Comment: Dariusz,thanks for your reply. I added the pom.xml and I did a `clean and build` for the project from netbeans. The results of that I have added to my question. The libraries exist, I could find them in the .m2 directorry as mentioned in the quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding the  section to the pom.xml file. I had gathered from the tutorial that this was only necessary when using a nightly build, as the provided pom.xml file did not have this tag as well. It all works well in Netbeans as well in Eclipse. The correct pom.xml is shown below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>14.2</geotools.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>  
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```